# Selenium Selenium.Core v1.1.4322 - XPath not working

Tags: unit-testing, xpath, selenium

I've got the following XPath expression's working in firebug, that returns the correct element(s):

`$x("(//input[@class='intervalInput timeInput'])")`, returns two elements.

```
$x("(//input[@class='intervalInput timeInput'])[1]") 
$x("(//input[@class='intervalInput timeInput'])[2]")
```

Each of the above return the correct element.

However; when I run the following code:

```
var matchedElements = this._selenium.GetXpathCount("(//input[@class='intervalInput timeInput'])");
```

The matched elements is 0.

I have also tried:

```
var matchedElements = this._selenium.GetXpathCount("xpath=(//input[@class='intervalInput timeInput'])");
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated,

Cheers.

Comment: Yes I put a Thread.Sleep before this and sure the element is loaded, I have been able to access the first element [1] but not [2], although as I said, I can access them both in firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have managed to resolve by using Selenium 2.0 as apposed to 1.0, apparently some issues with using XPATH 2.0 with Selenium 1.0 but seems to be working fine with 2.0.